# Extra,unwanted, row set by \cline

Tags: cline

I am trying to draw a kind of a table to be filled with Rufinni Method in the Spanish outlay. Everything works pretty good, but in order to get a `\cline{5-5}` in the end i have to type `\\ \cline{5-5}`, so an extra row is included. As a consequence, the vertical segment between the two first columns is extended.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{eqnarray}

\begin{document}
\begin{equationarray*}{c|cccc}
    &3  &-5 &0  &4  \\
 2  &   &6  &2  &4  \\ \cline{1-5}
    &3  &1  &2  &\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}8 \\ \cline{5-5}
\end{equationarray*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there any easy way to fix it? I mean to shorthen the first vertical line.

I got the next, but, despite it shows what i wanted, i don't like it because the extra line is still there.

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{eqnarray}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{equationarray*}{c|cccc}
    &3  &-5 &0  &4  \\
 2  &   &6  &2  &4  \\ \cline{1-5}
    &3  &1  &2  &\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}8 \\ \cline{5-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&&&&\phantom{-} %This is for the last segment not to be showed
\end{equationarray*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no reason for using the `equationarray` environment. You can obtain what you want with a plain `array`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
    &3  &-5 &0  &4  \\
 2  &   &6  &2  &4  \\ \cline{1-5}
    &3  &1  &2  &\multicolumn{1}{|@{}c}{}8 \\ \cline{5-5}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Easy and useful. The `|@{}c`string is totally unknown for me and i don't know how it works, but i asume that it places the vertical line right where i wanted. I appreciate this.

Comment: There is always an implicit space between columns: the string `@{}` suppresses it. Without it the `8` wouldn't be aligned with the other figures above it. Replacing centred columns `c` by right-aligned columns `r` as in Zarko's answer is another way.

Answer (score 4):

with `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[22]
\[\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{array}{r|rrrr}
    &3  &-5 &0  &4  \\
 2  &   &6  &2  &4  \\ \cline{1-5}
    &3  &1  &2  &\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}8 \\ \cline{5-5}
\end{array}
\]
\lipsum[33]
\end{document}
```